# Referencing a dynamic input ID in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the example below, I am trying to produce a box and plot for each group within a dataset, using `lapply` within a `renderUI` function. However, some of these groups require an additional filter as they have sub-groupings.

This means creating a `selectInput` inside the box for those groups only and having the corresponding chart reference that `selectInput` only.

Here's the reproducible example... my problem is in the `lapply` loop creating a `selectInput` with the `inputID` of `paste("selector_",i)` and then immediately referencing this in the data to be output inside the corresponding box with **input$(what goes here?)**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(DT)

data <- planes %>% 
  select(manufacturer, type, model, year, seats) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(year)) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.character(year))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Testing"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, selectInput("type","Type", choices = unique(data$type)),
             uiOutput("mytabs"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_filtered <- reactive({
    
    req(input$type)
    
    data %>% 
      filter(type == input$type)
    
  })
  
  mfrs <- reactive({
    
    data_filtered() %>% 
      select(manufacturer) %>% 
      unique() %>% 
      pull()
    
  })
  
  output$mytabs = renderUI({
    
    fluidRow(
      lapply(mfrs(), function(i) {
        
        dt <- data_filtered() %>% 
          filter(manufacturer == i) %>% 
          arrange(year) %>% 
          select(model, year, seats)
        
        models <- dt %>% 
          filter(!is.na(model)) %>% 
          select(model) %>% 
          unique() %>% 
          pull()
        
        if(length(models) > 1) {

          box(id = paste0('card', i), title = paste(i),

              selectInput(inputId = paste0("selector_",i), "Question",
                          choices = models, selected = models[1]),
              
              DT::datatable(dt[dt$qntext == input$the_one_above], 
                            width = "100%", rownames = F,
                            options = list(
                              columnDefs = list(list(width = '40px', targets = "_all"))
                            ))

          )

        } else {
          
          box(id = paste0('card', i), title = paste(i),
              
              DT::datatable(dt, 
                            width = "100%", rownames = F,
                            options = list(
                              columnDefs = list(list(width = '40px', targets = "_all"))
                            ))
              
          )
          
        }
      })
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `input[[paste("selector_",i)]]`

Comment: Thanks, but I get the result ```Input has size 3 but subscript `dt$model == input[[paste("selector_", i)]]` has size 0.``` .The selectInput has the wrong values (should be 'model' not 'qns' or 'qntext', sorry!) but the input is producing no output values.

Comment: You are correct as it has not rendered.  It might be better to have the `selectInput` in a separate `renderUI`.  You can use `uiOutput` of the first `renderUI` in which you have `selectInput`.

Comment: Thank you YBS. I don't know how I can put the input in a separate renderUI, as the inputs and outputs need to be 'paired' in separate boxes.

Comment: what is `qns` in `choices=qns`?

Answer (score 1):

Answered by the awesome Paul Campbell... using modules.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(nycflights13)

# Modules ===============================================

# UI and server module for box with chart
box_chart_UI <- function(id, title) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  box(
    title = title, height = 550,
    highcharter::highchartOutput(ns("chart"))
  )
}

box_chart <- function(input, output, session, df) {
  output$chart <- renderHighchart({
    validate(need(nrow(df) > 0, "No data"))
    hchart(df, "column", hcaes(year, seats))
  })
}

# UI and server module for box with chart and filter
box_chart_filter_UI <- function(id, title, filters, filter_lab = "Model") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  box(
    title = title, height = 550,
    selectInput(inputId = ns("selector"), label = filter_lab, choices = filters),
    highchartOutput(ns("chart"))
  )
}

box_chart_filter <- function(input, output, session, df) {
  output$chart <- renderHighchart({
    req(input$selector)
    df_chart <- df %>% filter(model == input$selector)
    validate(need(nrow(df_chart) > 0, "No data"))
    hchart(df_chart, "column", hcaes(year, seats))
  })
}

# Main App ===============================================

# load app data
data <- planes %>%
  select(manufacturer, type, model, year, seats) %>%
  unique() %>%
  filter(!is.na(year)) %>%
  mutate(year = as.character(year))


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Testing"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        selectInput("type", "Type", choices = unique(data$type))
      )
    ),
    uiOutput("mytabs")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_filtered <- reactive({
    req(input$type)
    data %>% filter(type == input$type)
  })

  mfrs <- reactive({
    data_filtered() %>%
      distinct(manufacturer) %>%
      pull()
  })

  # first load all the UI module functions
  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      lapply(1:length(mfrs()), function(i) {
        models <- data_filtered() %>%
          filter(manufacturer == mfrs()[i], !is.na(model)) %>%
          distinct(model) %>%
          pull() %>%
          sort()

        # depending on how many models, load the correct UI module
        if (length(models) > 1) {
          box_chart_filter_UI(id = i, title = mfrs()[i], filters = models)
        } else {
          box_chart_UI(id = i, title = mfrs()[i])
        }
      })
    )
  })

  # now separately load the module server functions
  # need to do this inside an observe due to reactive objects
  observe({
    lapply(1:length(mfrs()), function(i) {
      dt <- data_filtered() %>%
        filter(manufacturer == mfrs()[i]) %>%
        arrange(year) %>%
        select(model, year, seats)

      models <- dt %>%
        filter(!is.na(model)) %>%
        distinct(model) %>%
        pull() %>%
        sort()

      # depending on how many models, load the correct server module
      if (length(models) > 1) {
        callModule(box_chart_filter, id = i, df = dt)
      } else {
        callModule(box_chart, id = i, df = dt)
      }
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure what `qns` means, I have assigned `qns` to be models.  Try this code:

```
data <- planes %>% 
  select(manufacturer, type, model, year, seats) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(year)) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.character(year))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Testing"),
  dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("myqns")),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, selectInput("type","Type", choices = unique(data$type)), uiOutput("mytabs"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_filtered <- reactive({

    req(input$type)

    data %>%
      filter(type == input$type)

  })
  
  mfrs <- reactive({
    req(data_filtered())
    data_filtered() %>% 
      select(manufacturer) %>% 
      unique() %>% 
      pull()
    
  })
  
  output$myqns <- renderUI({
    req(mfrs())
    lapply(1:length(mfrs()), function(i) {
      dt <- data_filtered() %>% 
        filter(manufacturer == mfrs()[i]) %>% 
        arrange(year) %>% 
        select(model, year, seats)
      
      models <- dt %>% 
        filter(!is.na(model)) %>% 
        select(model) %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        pull()
      qns <- models
      
      selectInput(inputId = paste0("selector_",i), paste("Question",i), choices = as.list(qns), selected = 1)
    })
  })
  
  output$mytabs = renderUI({
    req(mfrs())
    fluidRow(
      lapply(1:length(mfrs()), function(i) {
        req(input[[paste0("selector_",i)]])
        dt <- data_filtered() %>% 
          filter(manufacturer == mfrs()[i]) %>% 
          arrange(year) %>% 
          select(model, year, seats)
        
        models <- dt %>% 
          filter(!is.na(model)) %>% 
          select(model) %>% 
          unique() %>% 
          pull()
        qns <- models
        if(length(models) > 1) {
          
          box(id = paste0('card', i), title = paste(mfrs()[i]),
              
              # selectInput(inputId = paste0("selector_",i), "Question",
              #             choices = qns, selected = qns[1]),
              
              DT::datatable(dt[dt$model == input[[paste0("selector_",i)]], ], 
                            width = "100%", rownames = F,
                            options = list(
                              columnDefs = list(list(width = '40px', targets = "_all"))
                            ))
              
          )
          
        } else {
          
          box(id = paste0('card', i), title = paste(mfrs()[i]),
              
              DT::datatable(dt, 
                            width = "100%", rownames = F,
                            options = list(
                              columnDefs = list(list(width = '40px', targets = "_all"))
                            ))
              
          )
          
        }
      })
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, `qns` should be `models` (my copy-and-paste fail when making the reproducible example).